# Do words, that have two stressed syllables, in sentences usually lose the secondary stress?

Tags: pronunciation

I read from a English speaking book, it said a sentence "It was controversial.", have only main stress when we speak - that is"It was contro**ver**sial".
Then I think secondary stress usually is lost when people speak.
Do I understand correctly ?

Comment: What secondary stress are you referring to?  Controversial only has the one stressed syllable - as you indicate.

Comment: @Chenmunka: on the first syllable

Comment: It's a  /ˌkɒn.trəˈvɜː.ʃəl /.

Comment: If we didn't (sometimes) use secondary stress for words in sentences, how would we remember where to put it in when we're pronouncing the words in isolation?

Answer (score 4):

English is a stress-timed language. One of the things that means is that we prefer not to have long strings of unstressed syllables, and we prefer not to have two stressed syllables in a row. (Don't take that last comment too seriously: in a phrase like "re**mote** **sens**ing, we're not going to unstress one of the syllables with primary stress.)

So in the sentence

> be**fore** the de**ci**sion, it was **con**tro**ver**sial,

**con** would have secondary stress. Unless we wanted to emphasize the fact that it used to be controversial but no longer is, or if we wanted to explain that it indeed was controversial to somebody who was denying that it was. Then we would put the stress on **was**, which tends to take it off **con**:

> be**fore** the de**ci**sion, it **was** contro**ver**sial.

The behavior of secondary stress varies between situations, between speakers, between dialects, and so forth. So you shouldn't worry too much about whether you're doing it right. Much of the time, there is no "right".

Comment: The bottom line being, "The behavior of secondary stress varies between situations, between speakers, between dialects, and so forth."

Answer (score 0):

Peter Shor has already taken a stab at answering this, and I think his answer is generally correct but I don't exactly agree with his examples and where he uses stress.  However, I do agree that in English usually the language is spoken in a way that creates a pattern of stressed and unstressed syllables, and to be more exact usually a slightly more stressed syllable will be created in the spoken language within 3 syllables following the prior stressed syllable.

The most extensive thought on stress in English language has probably been contributed by writers and critics of poetry, who generally will break down sentences into "feet", with each foot containing (usually) one stressed syllable and the most common feet being the:

- iamb (an unstressed syllable followed by a stressed one (shorthand: u ')
- trochee (a stressed syllable followed by an unstressed one (shorthand: ' u)
- anapest (two unstressed syllables followed by a stressed one (shorthand: u u ')
- dactyl (a stressed syllable followed by two unstressed ones (shorthand: ' u u)

There are other feet but these are the main four and will serve our purpose here so let's stick with them for now.  Poetic analysis would break "It was controversial" down as follows (I'm assuming the pronunciation [kon-truh-**vur**-shuh l] per dictionary.com:

**It** was (trochee ' u) **con**tro (trochee ' u) **ver**sial (dactyl ' u u)

However, if the phrase was lengthened (let's re-examine the phrase "before the decision, it was controversial" that Peter Shor suggested) the feet can change but the stressed syllables will remain (mostly) the same.  So:

be**fore** (iamb u ') the de**cis** (anapest u u ') ion, **it** (iamb u ') was **con** (iamb u ') tro**ver** (iamb u ') si**al** (iamb u ').

So note that adding the additional words changes the feet, but the stresses remain on "it", "con" and "ver" as before, **however**, also note that the longer phrase with it's generally iambic pattern *does* create an additional natural stress on the last syllable (on "al") that was not there with the shorter example above.  So, as English speakers begin to speak in a de-**duh** de-**duh** de-**duh** pattern that can create an extension of that pattern to cause the emphasis of a syllable that wasn't emphasized in the shorter phrase earlier.

As a caveat, some might argue that the comma between "decision" and "it" in the Peter Shor example can create a silent unstressed syllable so instead of:

-ion, **it** (iamb u ')

as I wrote above they might prefer:

-ion, **it** (anapest u u ')

where the silent unstressed comma stretches this iamb into an anapest; it really doesn't change my analysis but I just mention it to be completely accurate.

Comment: I (and I assume a lot of other Americans) never pronounce *controversial* with a *-see-al* ending; it's always *-shal; -see-al* sounds British to me, although I see that it is given as an alternate pronunciation in some American dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  "-shuh l" is the primary pronunciation given for Random House 2017 Dictionary.  I've lived in many locations in the United States, although admittedly more in the South and Southwest, and my experience is that pronunciation predominates.  In the South/Southwest people tend to slow their language and pronounce each syllable, but even in the New York area I heard probably a majority of "shuh l".  Admittedly New York is a cosmopolitan City with worldwide influence on the language so I might feel differently if I had lived in, say, Boston.